# Regex if string contains E or F letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to check if a string contains specific letters like `E` or `F`, with the following code

```
/^(F?)/.test('E22')
```

The problem is that it returns `true`, when it should return `false`. And what bothers me most, is that testing the regex at regexpal.com, goes perfect, but when applied... wrong.

Any idea what goes wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/alleks/CykQv/

### UPDATE

I have explained my self wrong. I do individual checks, in different cases. So, in specific cases I need to see if the string contains an `E`, and in others, if contains an `F`

```
//Case1
if (/^(F?)/.test(stringContainsE)) ....

//Case2
if (/^(F?)/.test(stringContainsF)) ....
```

### Update2

Both cases return TRUE when they shouldn't: http://jsfiddle.net/alleks/CykQv/2/

Comment: You have to read about regexps (see http://www.regular-expressions.info/). In the meantime, try with `/[EF]/g`.

Comment: Do the E and F have to occur at the beginning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match string not containing a word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Comment: @MikeEdwards Yea. The strings are `E**` or `F**`

Comment: lol, not sure why you even want regex. You could just access the first character using something like this [`str = "test"; alert(str[0]);`](http://jsfiddle.net/kPUAP/). After that it's just a matter of adding conditionals.

Comment: With regard to your second edit, you still are using a question mark.  Please read my updates below.  You don't need the capturing parentheses or the '?' to simply test for a single character at the beginning of a string.

Comment: @w0rldart: if you're testing whether the strings have a given letter at the start, then "contain" is the wrong word. "Contains F" means "Has an F somewhere inside it". You mean "starts with F".

Comment: @MikeEdwards My 2nd edit, was before seeing your answer...

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Thanks for the point! I have now a better notion on how to express my self, in such cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The question mark makes the F optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark).  That regex will return true for every single string.

```
/[EF]/
```

Will match strings that contain a letter E and/or a letter F.

**EDIT:** As Paul mentioned in his comment, the ^ character matches the beginning of the string.  If the character must occur at the beginning of the string then:

```
/^E/
```

will test for an E at the beginning of the string.  Simply omit the `^` if you want *anywhere* in the string.  However, in Javascript in this case you should simply use:

```
myString.charAt(0) === 'E' // for the beginning or
myString.indexOf('E') !== -1 // for anywhere
```

A regex for this simple operation is overkill.

Comment: Note that the original regex starts with the `^` character, which anchors matches at the start of the string. To match an `E` or an `F` at the start of the string, you'd do `/^[EF]/`.

Comment: I have miss explained my self. I don't need to check if contains `E` or `F` in same string

Comment: @w0rldart - do you mean it contains `E` and `F` in the same string?  `or` would only require one of them in the string.  `and` would require both to be present in the same string.  Which do you want?

Answer (score 5):

> `I'm trying to check if a string contains specific letters like E or F`

Regex should be:

```
/[EF]/.test('E22');
```

Your regex `^F?` makes F as optional which will always return true for any input.

**UPDATE:** This should work without optional anchor `?`

```
//Case1
if (/^E/.test(stringContainsE)) ....

//Case2
if (/^F/.test(stringContainsF)) ....
```

Comment: You have miss understood my question. I am trying to figure it out if the string contains an `E` or `F` in different cases... and never, both letters in the same string.